# Error with update() with web.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I'm trying to update a database row via a form POST with web.py, but I'm getting a MySQL syntax error. I'm new to Python in general, so forgive me for the newbie question. Here's the code I'm running:

```
   def Update(webInput):
      db.update('category', where='category_name=' + webInput.category_name)
      return;
```

The error I'm getting is

`ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category_name=' at line 1")`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [check the docs](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.db) for db.update. The correct call would be:

```
db.update('category', where='category_name = $category_name', vars=webInput, **webInput)
```

Assuming `webInput` holds the new data to be set.

`$category_name` in where clause is extracted from `vars` and sanitized (even if your code worked it would be vulnerable to sql injection).

Comment: I think I'm just thick. I tried the following:  db.update('category', where='categoryID= $category_id', vars=webInput) and I get the error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE categoryID= '8'' at line 1")'. I tried it without quotes 'where=category_id=$category_id, and I got an invalid syntax.

Comment: Update query is supposed to change values, you should pass the values that have to be updated in the database as keyword arguments. `vars` is only used in formatting `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting to pass in the data which you want to update 'category' with.

Try:

```
db.update('category', where='category_name=' + webInput.category_name, 'new data here')
```

Comment: You don't need to put quotes around strings in web.py database where statements? I'm just starting to learn about web.py

Comment: The new data is a form field named 'category_name'. How do I reference that? I thought it was through webInput.category_name